# Python only iterates through 37 user profiles to scrape - why not the full amount of elements found by BS4?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've recently implemented a scroll function for an infinite page, for a class I'm working on here:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchShadowRootException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

class MixCloudDiscover:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\mok_z\OneDrive\Desktop\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
        chrome_options = Options()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)
    
    def discover(self, terms):
        self.open_browser()
        mixcloud_data = []
        for term in terms:
            self.search(term)
            time.sleep(2)
            html = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, 'lxml')
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.scroll()
            time.sleep(5)
            cards = html.find_all('div', class_='styles__UserCardInformation-sc-f909fw-5 jEfkYy')
            #print(cards)
            time.sleep(5)
            for card in cards:
                user_profile_url = self.open_profile(card)
                self.driver.get(user_profile_url)
                link = user_profile_url
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print('Link: ' + user_profile_url)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                name = self.profile_scrape()[0]
                followers = self.profile_scrape()[1]
                bio = self.profile_scrape()[2]
                location = self.profile_scrape()[3]
                twitter = self.profile_scrape()[4]
                mixcloud_dict = {'Link':link, 'Curator':name, 'Followers':followers, 'Bio':bio, 'Location':location, 'Twitter':twitter}
                mixcloud_data.append(mixcloud_dict)
        self.driver.close()
        return mixcloud_data                
        
    def open_browser(self):
        url = 'https://www.mixcloud.com'
        self.driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.maximize_window()        

    def search(self, term):
        time.sleep(2)
        srch_click = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "mixcloud_query").click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        srch_keys = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "mixcloud_query").send_keys(term) #<<<<<(self.search)

    def get_html(self):
        html = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        return html
    
    def scroll(self):
            music_div = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body[class="rebrand"]')))
            music_div.click()
            #last_height = self.music_div.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            while True:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                music_div.send_keys(Keys.END)
                print('scrolled to bottom')
                songs = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class^="SearchAudioCard__SearchAudioCardContainer"]')))
                print('songs:', len(songs))
                print('______________-')
                if len(songs) > 3000:
                    print('stopping')
                    break
                        
    def open_profile(self, card):
        user_link_suffix = card.div.span.a['href']
        user_profile_url = f'https://www.mixcloud.com{user_link_suffix}'
        #print('Name: ' + user)
        return user_profile_url

    def pull_twitter(self, profile_html):       
        twitter = profile_html.find_all('div', class_='social-links')
        try:
            for t in twitter:
                t = twitter.a['href']
                #twitters.append(t)
                #print("Twitter: " + t)
                return t
        except:
            pass
    
    def pull_location(self, profile_html):
        location = profile_html.find('p', class_='profile-location')
        try:
            hq_white = location.text
            hq = str.strip(hq_white)
            #print('Location: ' + hq)
            return hq
        except:
            pass
    
    def pull_bio(self, profile_html):
        bio = profile_html.find('div', class_='profile-bio')
        try:
            bio_white = bio.text
            bio_strip = str.strip(bio_white)
            #print("Bio: " + bio_strip)
            return bio_strip
        except:
            pass

    def pull_followers(self, profile_html):
        header = profile_html.find('div', class_='cf')
        try: 
            for h in header:
                followers = h.h2.a.text
                #print("Followers: " + followers)
                return followers
        except:
            print("Can't pull followers")
    
    def profile_scrape(self):
        profile_html = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        #genres = []
        name = self.pull_name(profile_html)
        followers = self.pull_followers(profile_html)
        bio = self.pull_bio(profile_html)
        location = self.pull_location(profile_html)
        twitter = self.pull_twitter(profile_html)
        #genres.append(self.pull_genres(profile_html))
        return name, followers, bio, location, twitter
    
    #def pull_genre(self, profile_html):

    def pull_name(self, profile_html):
        name_element = profile_html.find('div', class_='profile-username')
        try:
            name = name_element.h1.text
            return name
            #print("Bio: " + bio_strip)
        except:
            pass
```

see 'scroll' function in particular. When ran through this here, I used to get a couple of hundred rows of data. However, now, I only get a MAX of 37.

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import pandas as pd
import MixcloudScraperDiscoverFunc as search

terms = ['house']
term_string = str(terms)
print(term_string)
discover = search.MixCloudDiscover()
discover_data = discover.discover(terms)
now = datetime.now()
fields = ['MixCloudLink', 'MixCloudName', 'MixCloudReach', 'Bio', 'Location', 'Twitter']
currentDateTime = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H-%M-%S %p")
mixcloud_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(discover_data)
print(mixcloud_df)
mixcloud_df.to_csv(f"Mixcloud_Data_{str(terms)}_{currentDateTime}.csv", index = False)
```

How can I ensure the code iterates through all of the 'cards' (user profiles) that can be found on the page provided, after the page has been scrolled? Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe the website has changed how they do pagination and so you need to do it again

Comment: They have an API, why not use that? https://www.mixcloud.com/developers/

Comment: @PaulCollingwood - I've watched the code. It's still one continuous, infinite page - the html shows all the elements I'm looking for, in the complete number, yet my code only iterates through a maximum of 37.

You'll have to excuse me - I've only been coding for 3 months. This is all very new to me, and based on what I know. I've not really delved into APIs, beyond trying to build one to scrape spotify playlist data from a comprehensive youtube tutorial.

Comment: There is such a large amount of code nobody is realistically going to be able to debug that for you. When you say you've "watched" the code, what does that mean?

Comment: It's likely that in order to reproduce the behavior you want you will need to emulate moving the mouse to the "bottom" of the screen to trigger the code to get the next page of results.

Comment: TLDR: An API won't change, your code will just "work" and continue to do so. A scraper will need constant maintenance as they change their site's UI.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood I watched the browser running through the code. The page UI and HTML remains - structurally - the same (I stopped the code and used inspector to check this).
I've already emulated scrolling manually. In inspector, the elements I need remain constant, and collect as more results appear, but do not move - there are far more than 37 available.

Comment: And yet it does not work! So _something_ is different in the way you are doing it and the way you are expecting it to be done. Get into an interactive ipython shell with bs4 and interact directly with the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I increased the sleep time immediately after `self.scroll()` to 20 seconds or more, for the page to load. The longer I waited, the more results I got in the end.